# Proving Inequality in Integration

Tags: integration, inequality

I need to prove that 
$$\int_{1}^{b}a^{\frac{\log x}{\log b}} dx > \ln b$$

I know that if somehow i can prove the function to be greater than $1/x$ then i would be able to prove the rest. but i can`t think of anything further.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: can anyone help me with the mathjax?

Comment: i tried but it didnt go right ofc

Comment: I have edited your mathjax but the integral is not properly defined as $\log x$ is not defined for $x<0$. I have missed something ?

Comment: Yes the lower limit is 1

Comment: $$
a^{(\log x)/(\log b)} = a^{\log_b x} = b^{(\log_b a)(\log_b x)} = x^{\log_b a}
$$
Therefore
$$
\int_1^b a^{(\log x)/(\log b)} \, dx = \int_1^b x^{\log_b a} \,dx = \left[ \frac{x^{1+\log_b a}}{1+\log_b a} \right]_{x\,:=\,1}^{x\,:=\,b} = \frac{ab - 1}{1+\log_b a}
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compute the integral:
$$a^\frac{\ln x}{\ln b}=\exp \left(\frac{\ln x \ln a}{\ln b} \right)=x^\frac{\ln a}{\ln b}$$
so if $\frac{\ln a}{\ln b} \neq -1$ :
$$I=\int_1^ba^\frac{\ln x}{\ln b} dx=\left[\frac{1}{\frac{\ln a}{\ln b} +1}x^{\left(\frac{\ln a}{\ln b} +1\right)}\right]_1^b$$
once more using the properties of the $\ln$:
$$b^{\left(\frac{\ln a}{\ln b} +1\right)}=\exp\left( \ln b\left(\frac{\ln a}{\ln b} +1 \right)\right)=\exp(\ln a +\ln b)=ab$$
so:
$$I=\ln(b) \left(\frac{\exp(\ln a +\ln b)-1}{\ln(a)+\ln(b)}\right)$$

From there if $\ln b$ and $\ln b+\ln a$ have the same sign you can use that $\forall z \in \Bbb R$ $e^z \geq 1+z$ to show that:

- If $\ln(b) > 0$ and $\ln(b)+\ln(a) > 0$:
  $$\frac{\exp(\ln a +\ln b)-1}{\ln(a)+\ln(b)} > 1$$
  so $$I > \ln(b)$$
- If $\ln(b) < 0$ and $\ln(b)+\ln(a) < 0$:
  $$\frac{\exp(\ln a +\ln b)-1}{\ln(a)+\ln(b)} < 1$$
  so $$I > \ln(b)$$
- In the other cases the inequality seems false.